# Binding a C++ _TCHAR to a C# string in a SWIG interface

Tags: c#, c++, xamarin.ios, swig

I have some old C++ code that I'm trying to compile as a DLL so that it can be used in a C# Xamarin.IOS project, using SWIG to create bindings for a wrapper between the C++ and the C#.

So far I have been able to get it working for all methods that take or return `int`, `double`, or `bool` parameters, but I'm stuck with how to deal with `_TCHAR`s.

Where the C++ code uses `_TCHAR`s as the parameter types, no matter what I've tried in the SWIG interface file, the C# parameters for any methods which should take a `string` are coming up as `SWIGTYPE_p__TCHAR`, which is as far as I can tell is what SWIG produces when it doesn't know what it should use.

I'm sure that this should be a case of using the right typemap in the SWIG interface file, but nothing I've tried so far has worked, any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the maintainer of the C++ code changed his code to use standard `char`s instead of `_TCHAR`s and I have managed to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

`TCHAR` is a preprocessor defined constant that is set at compile time `windows.h` based on the `UNICODE` preprocessor constant: if `UNICODE` is defined, it will either be `wchar_t`, otherwise it will be char. But you have to choose one: is your module unicode or ascii? If former, you should set UNICODE as part of your SWIG command:

```
swig -DUNICODE -c++ -csharp example.i
```

else

```
swig -c++ -csharp example.i
```

Since you are presumably doing latter, and getting this error, you probably forgot to `%include <windows.i>` after the preamble and before your declarations (if you have trouble, show your `.i` then I can be more specific).